# how to find which rules in decision tree that are causing misclassifications

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, random-forest, decision-tree

I built an binary decision tree  classifier . From the confusion matrix m i found class 0 is misclassified  495 times and class 1 is misclassified  134 times.I want to find which rules in the decision trees are actually causing the records to misclassify.

**In short which record failed at the which tree node**

**Is there a machine learning method which can be used to find the rules in the decision tree which are causing them to misclassify**

**Confusion Matrix**

```
[[14226   495]
 [  134  3271]]
```

**Fitting the decision tree and plotting it**

```
cv = CountVectorizer( max_features = 200,analyzer='word',ngram_range=(1, 3)) 
cv_addr = cv.fit_transform(data.pop('Clean_addr'))

for i, col in enumerate(cv.get_feature_names()):
    data[col] = pd.SparseSeries(cv_addr[:, i].toarray().ravel(), fill_value=0)

train = data.drop(['Resi], axis=1)
Y = data['Resi']
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(train, Y, test_size=0.3,random_state =8)
rus = RandomUnderSampler(random_state=42)
X_train_res, y_train_res = rus.fit_sample(X_train, y_train)

    dt=DecisionTreeClassifier(class_weight="balanced", min_samples_leaf=30)
    fit_decision=dt.fit(X_train_res,y_train_res)
    from sklearn.externals.six import StringIO  
    from IPython.display import Image  
    from sklearn.tree import export_graphviz
    import pydotplus
    dot_data = StringIO()
    export_graphviz(fit_decision, out_file=dot_data,  
                    filled=True, rounded=True,
                    special_characters=True,feature_names=train.columns)
    graph = pydotplus.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data.getvalue())  
    Image(graph.create_png())from sklearn.externals.six import StringIO  
    from IPython.display import Image  
    from sklearn.tree import export_graphviz
    import pydotplus
    dot_data = StringIO()
    export_graphviz(fit_decision, out_file=dot_data,  
                    filled=True, rounded=True,
                    special_characters=True,feature_names=train.columns)
    graph = pydotplus.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data.getvalue())  
    Image(graph.create_png())
```

Any help is appreciated.

**Dtree Plot**

[Decision Tree Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJc6b.jpg)

**Dataset**

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1NhXfwBIB640wJ30AyPKFnbIECCdmpyi5

Resi is the target  column . Using the other data columns i am trying to predict and I have countvectorized the Clean_addr column.

Comment: Is there any reason why you provide the full code for plotting your tree (which we cannot reproduce, since we don't have your data), without posting also the plot itself??

Comment: @desertnaut, I have updated the question with dataset and the plot of dtree. Sorry for not posting it before

Comment: Any  insights  people how to go about it